# Handling a stop or exit event in c++/cli console application

Tags: c++, .net, multithreading, event-handling, c++-cli

I have this following code in a console application where I am using TCP/IP connection to connect to the scanning device and after the connection is established, I am continuously getting the scan measurements.But I need the user to stop the measurement at any point.

I am thinking to get it done in the console application itself.Do I need to use threading for this?. If the user stop while the scanning is going on, I want to finish the particular scan and exit after that (something like locks).I am just learning c++ and c++/cli.. Any suggestions would be helpful.. thanks

```
if (sopas.GetScanData(soScan) == true)
 {
 printf("Continuous Scanning Measurement \n");
 processcounter = ProcessScan(soScan,processcounter,gp,Background);
 }
```

This skeleton of the process scan is

```
unsigned int ProcessScan(const SLms100Scan& soScan,int iProcessedScanCount,FILE* gp,vector <double> &Background)
{
        static unsigned int ulDeg90_index = 0; // Calculated during init phase
    static unsigned int ulProcessedScanCounter = 0;
    int iDataCount = soScan.aDataChannel16.aFlexArrayData[0].aData.uiFlexArrayLength;

    int datalength = soScan.aDataChannel16.aFlexArrayData[0].aData.uiFlexArrayLength;
    vector <double> afXvalue(datalength);
    vector <double> afYvalue(datalength);

    pair<double,double> coord(int a,int b);
    vector< pair<double,double>> coordinates;

    int aiDataReal[80];
    int count;

    //Finding the blobs

    // Write hex values of data in to the file
    int success = 0;
    writefile(fname,soScan,success);
    if (success != 0)
        {
        printf("Error in printing the file");
        }

    blobdetector(soScan, iProcessedScanCount,Background,coordinates);
    // Read the hex value for XY co-ordinate calculation
    //readfile(fname,aiDataReal,idx,success);

    if (success == -1)
        printf("Error in reading the file");

    //calculation of Polar Coardinates to XY values
    findXY(soScan,afXvalue,afYvalue);

    //writing the XY values to the file
    writefile( wfname_XY,iDataCount,afXvalue,afYvalue,success);
    if (success == -1)
        printf("Error in printing the file");

    plotdata(afXvalue,afYvalue,coordinates,gp,iProcessedScanCount);

    if (!coordinates.empty())
        {
        //sendcoordinates(soScan,coordinates);
        writefile( "coordinates",soScan,coordinates);
        coordinates.clear();
        }

    iProcessedScanCount++;
    return iProcessedScanCount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way (on windows) is to use [`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685049%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and then block termination until you finish your job, of course in case of `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` you only have a limited time on Win7/Vista.

You can use different mechanism to signal your main program to finish it's job. In my case I used a global variable in main file ,passed that by reference to my internal loop and used it as a loop termination condition. But it can be achieved with other methods too (`condition_variable`, ...)

Comment: can you give me an example..pls.. I have many functions inside the processscan function i given here. I dont know how to stop the processing of data in between and resume again until the whole proces scan function finish when the user gives a stop command..

Comment: If you have a main loop inside `PocessScan` you can check termination condition on that loop, if its more complex, you should check the condition in more places. If you're confused about what to do, it might be better to post skeleton of the `ProcessScan` method, and i'll try help you there.